# Difference between tortoise svn and CollabNetSubversion

Tags: svn

what is the Difference between tortoise svn and CollabNetSubversion.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One is a graphical client (or rather, a shell extension for Windows) and the other is a command-line client<sup>1</sup>. Usage differs greatly as do convenience features, however, the basic feature set to work with Subversion repositories is exactly the same as they both use the same library.

As for the Subversion server, that's actually a different piece of software, although it is sometimes distributed alongside with the command-line client.

---

1 Side note: I have long since stopped using the CollabNet-branded version because it's behind a registration wall. I found [Slik SVN](http://sliksvn.com/en/download/) as a good alternative. It's exactly the same command-line client you get from CollabNet, sans the hassle in downloading it.

Comment: ok then installing svn means we need to install svn server rt?is it different from both of these?

Comment: The server is yet another piece of software. It is included in some command-line SVN distributions, though.

Comment: ok that means shall i need to install server seperately or is it fine to install svnclient ?

Comment: This feature may have been added since the question was asked in 2010, but TortoiseSVN does now offer a command line client during custom installation (but it is not chosen by default, so you need to remember to check it every time you update). There is no need to have both programs installed.

Answer (score 1):

One (Tortoise) is a GUI and the other is a command-line tool. However, both are built with the same SVN libraries and can be used together to access the same repositories. Some things, like using within a script, are easier with the command-line (and vice versa, of course) - I find it desirable to have both installed.

Comment: No longer applicable - TortoiseSVN ships with a command line client.

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/), which is now supported by Apache, is a source control system.

Svn is the abbreviation for Subversion.

[Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a Subversion client, implemented as a Windows shell extension.

You have to install Subversion if you want a source control system.